# Is there a more efficient way of nesting logarithms?

Tags: recursion, numerical-methods, pari-gp

This is a continuation of the two questions posted here,

[Declaring a functional recursive sequence in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146061/declaring-a-functional-recursive-sequence-in-matlab)

[Nesting a specific recursion in Pari-GP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353022/nesting-a-specific-recursion-in-pari-gp)

To make a long story short, I've constructed a family of functions which solve the tetration functional equation. I've proven these things are holomorphic. And now it's time to make the graphs, or at least, somewhat passable code to evaluate these things. I've managed to get to about 13 significant digits in my precision, but if I try to get more, I encounter a specific error. That error is really nothing more than an overflow error. But it's a peculiar overflow error; Pari-GP doesn't seem to like nesting the logarithm.

My particular mathematical function is approximated by taking something large (think of the order e^e^e^e^e^e^e) to produce something small (of the order e^(-n)). The math inherently requires samples of large values to produce these small values. And strangely, as we get closer to numerically approximating (at about 13 significant digits or so), we also get closer to overflowing because we need such large values to get those 13 significant digits. I am a god awful programmer; and I'm wondering if there could be some work around I'm not seeing.

```
/*
This function constructs the approximate Abel function
The variable z is the main variable we care about; values of z where real(z)>3 almost surely produces overflow errors
The variable l is the multiplier of the approximate Abel function
The variable n is the depth of iteration required
n can be set to 100, but produces enough accuracy for about 15 
The functional equation this satisfies is exp(beta_function(z,l,n))/(1+exp(-l*z)) = beta_function(z+1,l,n); and this program approaches the solution for n to infinity
*/

beta_function(z,l,n) =
{
    my(out = 0);
    for(i=0,n-1,
        out = exp(out)/(exp(l*(n-i-z)) +1));
    out;
}

/*
This function is the error term between the approximate Abel function and the actual Abel function
The variable z is the main variable we care about
The variable l is the multiplier
The variable n is the depth of iteration inherited from beta_function
The variable k is the new depth of iteration for this function
n can be set about 100, still; but 15 or 20 is more optimal. 
Setting the variable k above 10 will usually produce overflow errors unless the complex arguments of l and z are large. 
Precision of about 10 digits is acquired at k = 5 or 6 for real z, for complex z less precision is acquired. k should be set to large values for complex z and l with large imaginary arguments.
*/

tau_K(z,l,n,k)={
    if(k == 1, 
      -log(1+exp(-l*z)), 
      log(1 + tau_K(z+1,l,n,k-1)/beta_function(z+1,l,n)) - log(1+exp(-l*z))
    )
}

/*
This is the actual Abel function
The variable z is the main variable we care about
The variable l is the multiplier
The variable n is the depth of iteration inherited from beta_function
The variable k is the depth of iteration inherited from tau_K
The functional equation this satisfies is exp(Abl_L(z,l,n,k)) = Abl_L(z+1,l,n,k); and this function approaches that solution for n,k to infinity
*/

Abl_L(z,l,n,k) ={
    beta_function(z,l,n) + tau_K(z,l,n,k);
}
```

This is the code for approximating the functions I've proven are holomorphic; but sadly, my code is just horrible. Here, is attached some expected output, where you can see the functional equation being satisfied for about 10 - 13 significant digits.

```
Abl_L(1,log(2),100,5)

%52 = 0.1520155156321416705967746811

exp(Abl_L(0,log(2),100,5))

%53 = 0.1520155156321485241351294757

Abl_L(1+I,0.3 + 0.3*I,100,14)

%59 = 0.3353395055605129001249035662 + 1.113155080425616717814647305*I

exp(Abl_L(0+I,0.3 + 0.3*I,100,14))

%61 = 0.3353395055605136611147422467 + 1.113155080425614418399986325*I

Abl_L(0.5+5*I, 0.2+3*I,100,60)

%68 = -0.2622549204469267170737985296 + 1.453935357725113433325798650*I

exp(Abl_L(-0.5+5*I, 0.2+3*I,100,60))

%69 = -0.2622549205108654273925182635 + 1.453935357685525635276573253*I
```

Now, you'll notice I have to change the k value for different values. When the arguments z,l are further away from the real axis, we can make k very large (and we have to to get good accuracy), but it'll still overflow eventually; typically once we've achieved about 13-15 significant digits, is when the functions will start to blow up.  You'll note, that setting k =60, means we're taking 60 logarithms. This already sounds like a bad idea, lol. Mathematically though, the value Abl_L(z,l,infinity,infinity) is precisely the function I want. I know that must be odd; nested infinite for-loops sounds like nonsense, lol.

I'm wondering if anyone can think of a way to avoid these overflow errors and obtaining a higher degree of accuracy. In a perfect world, this object most definitely converges, and this code is flawless (albeit, it may be a little slow); but we'd probably need to increase the stacksize indefinitely. In theory this is perfectly fine; but in reality, it's more than impractical. Is there anyway, as a programmer, one can work around this?

The only other option I have at this point is to try and create a bruteforce algorithm to discover the Taylor series of this function; but I'm having less than no luck at doing this. The process is very unique, and trying to solve this problem using Taylor series kind of takes us back to square one. Unless, someone here can think of a fancy way of recovering Taylor series from this expression.

I'm open to all suggestions, any comments, honestly. I'm at my wits end; and I'm wondering if this is just one of those things where the only solution is to increase the stacksize indefinitely (which will absolutely work). It's not just that I'm dealing with large numbers. It's that I need larger and larger values to compute a small value. For that reason, I wonder if there's some kind of quick work around I'm not seeing. The error Pari-GP spits out is always with tau_K, so I'm wondering if this has been coded suboptimally; and that I should add something to it to reduce stacksize as it iterates. Or, if that's even possible. Again, I'm a horrible programmer. I need someone to explain this to me like I'm in kindergarten.

Any help, comments, questions for clarification, are more than welcome. I'm like a dog chasing his tail at this point; wondering why he can't take 1000 logarithms, lol.

Regards.

EDIT:

I thought I'd add in that I can produce arbitrary precision but we have to keep the argument of `z` way off in the left half plane. If the variables `n,k = -real(z)` then we can produce arbitrary accuracy by making `n` as large as we want. Here's some output to explain this, where I've used `\p 200` and we pretty much have equality at this level (minus some digits).

```
Abl_L(-1000,1+I,1000,1000)

%16 = -0.29532276871494189936534470547577975723321944770194434340228137221059739121428422475938130544369331383702421911689967920679087535009910425871326862226131457477211238400580694414163545689138863426335946 + 1.5986481048938885384507658431034702033660039263036525275298731995537068062017849201570422126715147679264813047746465919488794895784667843154275008585688490133825421586142532469402244721785671947462053*I

exp(Abl_L(-1001,1+I,1000,1000))

%17 = -0.29532276871494189936534470547577975723321944770194434340228137221059739121428422475938130544369331383702421911689967920679087535009910425871326862226131457477211238400580694414163545689138863426335945 + 1.5986481048938885384507658431034702033660039263036525275298731995537068062017849201570422126715147679264813047746465919488794895784667843154275008585688490133825421586142532469402244721785671947462053*I

Abl_L(-900 + 2*I, log(2) + 3*I,900,900)

%18 = 0.20353875452777667678084511743583613390002687634123569448354843781494362200997943624836883436552749978073278597542986537166527005507457802227019178454911106220050245899257485038491446550396897420145640 - 5.0331931122239257925629364016676903584393129868620886431850253696250415005420068629776255235599535892051199267683839967636562292529054669236477082528566454129529102224074017515566663538666679347982267*I

exp(Abl_L(-901+2*I,log(2) + 3*I,900,900))

%19 = 0.20353875452777667678084511743583613390002687634123569448354843781494362200997943624836883436552749978073278597542986537166527005507457802227019178454911106220050245980468697844651953381258310669530583 - 5.0331931122239257925629364016676903584393129868620886431850253696250415005420068629776255235599535892051199267683839967636562292529054669236477082528566454129529102221938340371793896394856865112060084*I

Abl_L(-967 -200*I,12 + 5*I,600,600)

%20 = -0.27654907399026253909314469851908124578844308887705076177457491260312326399816915518145788812138543930757803667195961206089367474489771076618495231437711085298551748942104123736438439579713006923910623 - 1.6112686617153127854042520499848670075221756090591592745779176831161238110695974282839335636124974589920150876805977093815716044137123254329208112200116893459086654166069454464903158662028146092983832*I

exp(Abl_L(-968 -200*I,12 + 5*I,600,600))

%21 = -0.27654907399026253909314469851908124578844308887705076177457491260312326399816915518145788812138543930757803667195961206089367474489771076618495231437711085298551748942104123731995533634133194224880928 - 1.6112686617153127854042520499848670075221756090591592745779176831161238110695974282839335636124974589920150876805977093815716044137123254329208112200116893459086654166069454464833417170799085356582884*I
```

The trouble is, we can't just apply `exp` over and over to go forward and expect to keep the same precision. The trouble is with `exp`, which displays so much chaotic behaviour as you iterate it in the complex plane, that this is doomed to work.

Comment: I'm sure you can express `tau_K()` iteratively.

Comment: @user207421 Could you elaborate further as to what you mean by this? I'm a horrible programmer; I've only dealt with functions in theory, never in actual real world examples. I'm a pure mathematician by trade, and I've never had to deal with a problem like this when programming.

Comment: @user207421 Wait, are you suggesting calculating Abl_L(z,l,n,k) for large values of n and k, but for values z way way off in the left half plane (which would be real(z) < -100) for instance, and then pushing forward by applying exp over and over? I'm wary of doing this, largely because the exponential, and the iterates of the exponential are highly highly volatile. And any small error, will produce more and more errors as we go out.

Comment: I am suggesting iterative programming instead of recursive programming. I haven't said one word about half planes or any of the rest of it. I understand that the mathematical definition is recursive but there is nothing about the problem that requires recursion in the programming sense. Just iterate over `k` reducing it until it reaches one, where you apply your terminating case.

Comment: @user207421 I'm confused by  "Just iterate over k reducing it until it reaches one, where you apply your terminating case." Isn't that what I'm doing by calling ```tau_K(...,k-1)``` in ```tau_K(...,k)```. How is an iterative procedure any better? It'll still suffer the e^e^e^e^e^e^e kind of problem I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my own question. @user207421 posted a comment, and I'm not sure if it meant what I thought it meant, but I think it got me to where I want. I sort of assumed that `exp` wouldn't inherit the precision of its argument, but apparently that's true. So all I needed was to define,

```
Abl_L(z,l,n,k) ={
    if(real(z) <= -max(n,k),
    beta_function(z,l,n) + tau_K(z,l,n,k),
    exp(Abl_L(z-1,l,n,k)));
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine from here; of course, for what I need it for. So, I answered my own question, and it was pretty simple. I just needed an `if` statement.

Thanks anyway, to anyone who read this.